# Traducir este pequeño código de c# a vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hola estaba intentando traducir este pequeño código que de momento me da varios errores y no consigo hacer la traducción correctamente a c# sin errores sintácticos o convirtiendolo directamente con telerik(muchas veces comete faltas al traducirlo). Entonces el código es el siguiente:

```
private static Byte[] ToShellcodeBytes(String shellcode)
        {
            Byte[] sc_bytes = new Byte[shellcode.Length];
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < shellcode.Length; i++) 
            {
                sc_bytes [i] = (Byte) shellcode [i];
            }

            return sc_bytes;
        }
```

He hecho la traducción del siguiente modo:

```
Private Function ToShellcodeBytes(shellcode As [String]) As [Byte]()
        Dim sc_bytes As [Byte]() = New [Byte](shellcode.Length - 1) {}
        For i = 0 To shellcode.Length Step 1
            sc_bytes(i) = DirectCast(shellcode(i), [Byte])
        Next

        Return sc_bytes
    End Function
```

Pero me muestra los errores:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error BC32006 'Char' values cannot be converted to 'Byte'. Use
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW' to interpret a character as a Unicode
>   value or 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val' to interpret it as a
>   digit.    shellcode   c:\users\androide\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Project\Form1.vb 31  Active Error    BC30201 Expression
>   expected. shellcode   c:\users\androide\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Form1.vb    17  Active

Lo quería hacer una traduccion igual de funcional y correcta en vb.net por lo que cuando llame esta función me devolverá los bytes del código, solo con fines educativos.

Por lo que al final cuando llame a la función en vb.net hará lo mismo, ej..

```
Dim m as String = ToShellcodeBytes(String shellcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta línea dentro del `For`:

```
sc_bytes(i) = Convert.ToByte(shellcode(i))
```

o también con esta:

```
sc_bytes(i) = CType(shellcode(i), [Byte])
```

De esta manera haces una conversión y no un *cast* (el cual implica que el objeto a *castear* **ya sea** del tipo destino, lo que no es tu caso).

La diferencia es que un **cast** es un simple *cambio de tipo*, por ejemplo convertir un arreglo de caracteres a una cadena; como [lo define la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator):

> `DirectCast` requiere una herencia o relación de implementación entre los tipos de datos de los dos argumentos.

Por otro lado, [`CType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function):

> Devuelve el resultado de *convertir explícitamente* una expresión a un tipo de dato especificado, objeto, estructura, clase, o interfaz.

y [`Convert.ToByte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee6e613x(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

> Este método devuelve un valor byte sin signo que representa el código numérico del objeto `Char` usado como parámetro.